# mysql full text search is empty

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am using ruby on rails with a MySQL backend.  I have a table called notes and here is the migration I use to create it:

```
def self.up
  create_table(:notes, :options => 'ENGINE=MyISAM') do |t|
    t.string :title
    t.text :body

    t.timestamps
  end

  execute "alter table notes ADD FULLTEXT(title, body)"

end
```

I want to do full text searches on the title and body fields.  The problem is that the full text searches always come back empty.  For example if I add this row into the database: `Title: test, Body: test`.  Then I run this query `SELECT * FROM notes WHERE MATCH(title, body) AGAINST('test')`.  It returns a nil set.  Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong and how to get full text search working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm just guessing here, but the documentation states:

> A natural language search interprets
>   the search string as a phrase in
>   natural human language (a phrase in
>   free text). There are no special
>   operators. The stopword list applies.
>   In addition, words that are present in
>   50% or more of the rows are considered
>   common and do not match. Full-text
>   searches are natural language searches
>   if the IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE
>   modifier is given or if no modifier is
>   given.

Therefore, if there is only one row, and it contains 'test', then 'test' is present in  more than 50% of the rows and is therefore not considered a match.  Perhaps try:

```
SELECT * FROM notes WHERE MATCH(title, body) AGAINST('test' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Answer (score 0):

While this probably does not answer your specific question, I would just go ahead and use [Ferret](http://rm.jkraemer.net/projects/show/aaf) or [Solr](http://acts-as-solr.rubyforge.org/) as the search engine, especially if lots of text is involved. Both are very easy to setup and powerful to boot. Ultrasphinx is also another option.

With RoR, I usually don't get bogged trying to get something to work in one particular way. It's all about being Agile ;) you see.